# Why does const std::array<std::array<float, 1081>, 2>& wavetable_h not point to the original array?

Tags: c++, pointers, stdarray

I thought when you used `const std::array<float> & arr` the new array just pointed to the adress of the original array yet in my code when I change the original array the `const array<>&` doesn't change with it.

This means I have to set it constantly in my main loop instead of just once before entering the main loop. Any idea what I need to do to have it not copy and some explanation of why it's wrong would be appreciated.

main.cpp:

```
void GeoHeadAudioProcessor::processBlock (juce::AudioBuffer<float>& buffer, juce::MidiBuffer& midiMessages)
{
    juce::ScopedNoDenormals noDenormals;
    buffer.clear();
    proc0.setWavetable(waveforms); //Need to set it every time because it doesn't copy 
    proc1.setWavetable(waveforms); // causes glitches to slow
    proc0.processBlock(buffer, midiMessages);    
    proc1.processBlock(buffer, midiMessages);

}
public:
std::array<std::array<float, 1081>, 2> waveforms = {{ {0}, {0} }};
```

oscillatorprocessor.cpp :

```
public:
     void setWavetable(const std::array<std::array<float, 1081>, 2>& wavetable_h)
      {
         wavetable = wavetable_h;
      }
      void processBlock()
      {
         voice->setWavetable(wavetable, id);
      }

private:
     std::array<std::array<float, 1081>, 2> wavetable;
     SynthVoice* voice;
```

SynthVoice:

```
public:
   void setWavetable(const std::array<std::array<float, 1081>, 2>& wavetable_h, int id_h)
       {
           wavetable = wavetable_h;
           id = id_h;
        }
```

Comment: `taught` (past of 'teach') or `thought` (past of 'think')?

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding of `&` is fine, but the problem lies in the class SynthVoice:

```
public:
   void setWavetable(
       const std::array<std::array<float, 1081>, 2>& wavetable_h, // A
       int id_h
   )
   {
       wavetable = wavetable_h;  // B
       id = id_h;
   }
```

I reformatted it a bit so I can mark things with A and B. While you have focused on A, which in deed is a reference to the array, look at line marked as B.

In that line, you are assigning the `wavetable_h` to .. something.

And that something, called `wavetable`, probably a field of class SynthVoice, probably is just a field. You wouldn't be able to assign to a `array<...>& wavetable`, because references are not assignable, it wouldn't compile. So most probably, the `wavetable` variable is a `array`, non-reference.

This in turn means, that line B copies what's passed as reference in line A, into variable `wavetable`. And that is why you observe that the array is not updating when you change it at the original location. The `wavetable` of SynthVoice is not a reference. It's a copy, so that copy is not 'updating itself' when you change the original thing.

Oh, I just noticed the oscillatorpreprocessor.cpp snippet. It has the same problem - and it looks exactly as I guessed in SynthVoice - `std::array<std::array<float, 1081>, 2> wavetable;`

If you changed it to anything like

```
std::array<std::array<float, 1081>, 2>& wavetable;
std::array<std::array<float, 1081>, 2>* wavetable;
std::shared_ptr<std::array<std::array<float, 1081>, 2>> wavetable;
std::reference_wrapper<std::array<std::array<float, 1081>, 2>> wavetable;
// ...
```

that it would be reference-ish and point to the original. Each of those examples shown has its own quirks, so consider them carefully. But each of them is some kind of a reference/pointer to the original, while `std::array<std::array<float, 1081>, 2>& wavetable;` is just a new separate thing.

Comment: Thanks!
I changed it to std::array<std::array<float, 1081>, 2>* wavetable; in A and B, but now when I try to acces it like:
float sampleCur = *wavetable[id][first_sample + (int) phase_0];
It gives the
error: no match for ‘operator*’ (operand type is ‘std::array<std::array<float, 1081>, 2>::value_type’

How do I acces it?

Comment: @DedicatedDreamer when you added `*`, the `wavetable` variable became a pointer. It's similar to a reference in its core, but its usage is a bit different - references are used just like normal things, but pointers need to be dereferenced. Like `foo.bar` versus `this->bar`. Unfortunatelly, `->` operator won't help here, you can't write `foo->[idx]`. Use good old `*` instead: `float sampleCur = (*wavetable)[id][...];` or in a overly verbose way to emphasize what happens: `std::array<std::array<float, 1081>, 2>& the_reference= *wavetable;  float sampleCur = the_reference[id][...];`

Answer (score 1):

Because `wavetable` is your class's private member stored by-value, so when you assign another array to it, that array is copied into `wavetable`. Consequently, changing one does not affect the other.